# Error when brace-expansion includes more than ~25 files in amazon-s3 read from spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, brace-expansion

I have just upgraded to using spark 3 instead of spark 2.4.

The following code ran fine in spark 2.4

```
df = spark.read.parquet('s3a://bucket/path/{'+
                                      'file1,'+
                                      'file2,'+
                                      'file3,'+
                                      'file4,'+
                                      'file5,'+
                                      'file6,'+
                                      'file7,'+
                                      'file8,'+
                                      'file9,'+
                                      'file10,'+
                                      'file11,'+
                                      'file12,'+
                                      'file13,'+
                                      'file14,'+
                                      'file15,'+
                                      'file16,'+
                                      'file17,'+
                                      'file18,'+
                                      'file19,'+
                                      'file20,'+
                                      'file21,'+
                                      'file22,'+
                                      'file23,'+
                                      'file24,'+
                                      'file25'+
                                      '}')
```

but in spark 3 I get this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o944.parquet.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSS3IOException: getFileStatus on s3a://

...

com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: aaa), S3 Extended Request ID:
```

If I reduce the number of files to less than about 24 then the query completes successfully in spark 3.

I can't find any reference to limits on the number of files in a brace expansion like this in s3. What might be going wrong? How can it be fixed?

Comment: no idea why, but you can provide a Python list of filename strings instead of using brace expansion.

Answer (score 0):

why not just give spark the entire directory to process and let it scan the files?

```
df = spark.read.parquet('s3a://bucket/path/')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to 1024 characters in a aws query. Somehow, this was not a problem in spark 2.